# Information about Suggested Edits completely missing from FAQs and privileges pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, suggested-edits, site-faq

When the SE team implemented the Suggested Edits feature, they did not update the documentation to reflect the changes made. Currently, no info is available outside of MSO.

The FAQs does not mention that a confirmed edit gives +2 reputation while listing the ways to acquire reputation, the [privileges/edit page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) is still written under the assumption that no one under 2k can edit posts, there is no mention of edit review privileges on the privileges page, etc.

Is that an oversight or is it [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)?

Answer (score 2):

This has now been added to the faq.

Comment: The privileges are still missing from [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) though. Shouldn't it say something when you get the rights to approve edits?