# +2 for edit suggestion not in FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, suggested-edits, site-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Information about Suggested Edits completely missing from FAQs and privileges pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78047/information-about-suggested-edits-completely-missing-from-faqs-and-privileges-pag)

I noticed today that I got **+2** reputation for making an edit suggestion that was approved on SuperUser.

This surprised me a bit, as I didn't recall seeing it anywhere, so I consulted the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), which lists the different ways of gaining/losing reputation in the **What is reputation?** section, only to not find anything that could explain a **+2** gain there.

It wasn't until I found "[Edit a question (from other user) and get +2 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep)" here on Meta, that I realized what was going on.

In short, the **+2** reputation gain from an accepted edit suggestion is missing from the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

The edit suggestion system is currently under testing and has not been officially announced. Any details about how it works are under flux and can change at any moment as the SO team tries out various tweaks. As such, it's a bit early to write FAQ entries on it :)