# Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, edit-ban

As mentioned in [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78047/information-about-suggested-edits-completely-missing-from-faqs-and-privileges-pag), approval of an edit suggestion gives the suggester +2 reputation.

If the suggestion is rejected, does it cost the suggester any rep?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, but repeated edit suggestion rejections from multiple users will cause your edit suggestion rights to be suspended for (n) days, where n is currently 7.

Note that after a recent change, automatic rejections due to edit conflicts [are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/152859) and won't affect the suggested edit ban mechanism. (only rejections made by actual users)

Comment: I got hit with this in making tag wiki edit suggestions. I have no idea why, since most of my suggestions were adding tag-wiki excerpts to tags which didn't have them. Honestly, I feel smacked for trying to make the site better. http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/911/how-can-i-tell-which-of-my-tag-wiki-edits-are-rejected-and-why :(

Comment: Can you please clarify this? I've made a lot of edit suggestions recently, some of which were rejected. I don't want to risk getting blocked, so I'd like to know what the criteria for a block are. As I'm reading it, _multiple rejected suggestions __in a row__ with different people rejecting each suggestion will get you blocked. If you make an approved suggestion in-between those rejected ones, you won't._ Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

No.

I have no facts backing up this answer but, doing so would be incredible stupid as it would discourage people from trying to make SE a better place.

And since the SE team make 84.76% more good decisions than bad I'm betting the answer is no.

Comment: Technically it would discourage people from trying to make SE a *worse* place (since edit suggestions are generally approved unless they reduce the quality of the post), similar to how the existence of answer downvotes discourages people from posting terrible answers. But I think you're right that there's no penalty