# Unable to find "edit" link on any questions or answers

Tags: support, edits

[image: screenshot]

(The screenshot is also a link to the question.)

Since yesterday, I have not been able to see the **edit** link below questions or answers on Stack Overflow. Have I made some mistake that Stack Overflow is punishing me for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got some suggested edits rejected yesterday, this cause a temporary "edit ban" [for 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/152859).

Please see the reasons, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/209215) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/209201) and try to improve your edits in the future.

One tip comes to mind: keep track of your suggestion (you can see them all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109930/shahzad-imam?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)) this way you can know when some are rejected and expect a temporary ban before it happens.

Comment: Got it but may i know what is no of days for this ban

Comment: Yes, I've added it to my post with link to the official post explaining it. (7 days)

Comment: Thanx...You solved a complex riddle......Now i have to take precautions for such edits........

Comment: The rejected edits are not more than 2 in row, and those are the last ones. Isn't the edit ban raised if the rejected edits are X (> 2) and consecutive?

Comment: @kiamlaluno the exact algorithm is secret, I assume it's X rejected edits over Y period of time, rejected by Z different users.