# Unable to edit questions

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to find “edit” link on any questions or answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123613/unable-to-find-edit-link-on-any-questions-or-answers)

I am unable to edit questions on SO. Earlier, I was able to. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I strongly believe this is new feature in Stack Overflow, where before the link used to show and say "you can't do that" after clicking but now the link would not even show.. can you confirm this somehow?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Last time I had this edit ban, I got the message saying that I was edit-banned and I could try again after 7 days.

Comment: @kiamlaluno so obviously no message this time otherwise we wouldn't have seen this influx of same posts. Waiting for some official confirmation though. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite a few of your [suggested edits were rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098379/sans481?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Considering this, your editing privileges has been revoked for a week.

Please consider reviewing your edits & take time to reflect and understand why they were rejected.