# Why am I not allowed to edit posts?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, privileges

I am a regular Stack Overflow user and participate in questions and answers. Sometimes I edit questions or answers, but from few days ago I do not have the privilege to edit questions. When I take the cursor to edit button it shows this message:

> **account not allowed to suggest edits**

Why is this happening? When will I get the privilege back to editing and what should I do for not to lose this privilege  again?

Comment: -1 for not letting people fix your grammar mistakes. In English, first letter in a sentence should be upper case and "i" should be "I" to refer to yourself.

Comment: No it is not like that  i felt i have some error i just tried to correct my mistake , not stopping others to correct

Comment: i was just editing and was not aware of that , this will rollback the other edits

Comment: No no, don't touch it now please, I've fixed all the mistakes. Unless of course you have something more to post. Anyway, you had your edit page open for over 20 minutes? Didn't you see the "the post was edited, please reload" message?

Comment: Ya sure i shall not :)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard Use first form verb after "to"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got too many suggested edit you made rejected, so you are [banned from making new suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192) for seven days.

You can see your suggestion history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766108/avi-kumar-manku?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

From quick look in your suggestions, you are adding incorrect tags or making bold stuff instead of formatting it properly. Just think twice before making an edit  and you should be fine, the ban should be lifted automatically within 5 days, as you last rejected edit (which triggered the ban) was two days ago.

Comment: so i should avoid formatting if it is only formatting error like they did not use formatting tools like for code  or small typing errors

Comment: thanks buddy to make me understand it better :)

Comment: can you tell me one thing more after how many rejections of edit my edit privilege will be lost

Comment: You should format properly. If you don't know how to do that yourself, please don't try to suggest edits with this. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn more. As for how many rejections it's not public information but I believe it's around five, don't have to be in a row.

Comment: @Avi - I don't think it is a certain number, but a high percentage of your latest edits and/or several rejected edits in a row.

Comment: @AviKumarManku here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/317831) - you put two unrelated blocks of cod together. This is wrong, they should be separate because they are written in different languages.

Comment: i shall be careful for next time when i get my privilege back , thanks @Bo Persson and Sha Wiz Dow Ard

Answer (score 11):

For future editing efforts, here are some pointers why the edits were (probably) rejected:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314098:

- Don't highlight entire paragraphs with bold text. As a personal rule I never highlight anything the original question didn't have highlighted.
- You changed the grammatically correct "I have a problem with" to "I have a problem in".

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/310630:

- You changed the topic "cusoradapter lisiview in android" to "cusor adapter lisiview in android" - there's still two typos and missing capitalization.
- "But i cant able to show data in cursor adapter" to "But i am mot add  data in cursor adapter" - the edit is just gibberish, even worse than the original from where you could easily grasp the idea even if it weren't grammatically perfect.
- You didn't fix the missing spaces after punctuation and lacking capitalization.

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/313866:

- The entire answer was in bold text, but I'm not sure if it's any better to have it in code format when it doesn't contain a single line of code.

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/266772:

- All you did was move two text paragraphs inside the code format block - a rather baffling move.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Juhana , I shall keep this in mind

Comment: +1 you put more effort than me, lol.. :)