# Edit no longer enabled after categorizing a number of questions

Tags: support, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I not allowed to edit posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140370/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-edit-posts)

I've started cleaning up a number of questions related to a rarely used keyword, i.e. adding tags to related questions and removing the tag from wrongly tagged questions.

However, after a number of edits (I'd say about 10??) I cannot edit **any** post any more.

The `Edit` button is simply disabled for every question - anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the ability to actually *edit* questions until you hit 2000 reputation (you have ~450 at this writing). Until then, you can make edit *suggestions*, which must be approved by (in the case of Stack Overflow) two other 2k+ users, or rejected by two 2k+ users.

You've had a large number of your edit suggestions rejected. Once you've hit a limit, you're prevented from making any further suggestions for a week.

Looking over your suggestions, it looks like a large number of them have been rejected for being too minor. Quoting from the rejection reason, *This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post*.  As Lucifer says, adding or removing a tag by itself isn't considered a substantive edit. Look around for other positive changes you can make to posts. They're almost always there.

Take [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/731694) at random: lots of juicy product naming issues, and a title that could use clarification.

Comment: Hmm.. categorizing questions so you can find them is irrelevant? Interesting.

Comment: How on earth did you get that from my answer, @Jay?

Comment: Well - that's all the rejected edits were about and why I'm now 'locked out' :-)

Comment: +1 ( already done )for added my name :P

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding a tag is not always a good edit. You have only added a tag in 4-5 posts only.

> [spotlight] tag added as the question refers to the Spotlight search technology in OS X

This is really not an edit, and you have repeated the same edit for more than one post.

Users with more than 2K reputation have reviewed your posts and **rejected** it. When 6 (or more) posts get rejected, the system will not allow you to edit more posts.

Now you have to wait probably a week to pass for coming out from this edit suspension period.

From your profile [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089245/jay?tab=activity) page, it seems you have just started editing yesterday. Your first post for the same edit has been [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/731693). But it doesn't mean the same editing can work on other posts too. That's why the same edit was rejected.

Comment: Yeah - because I was categorizing relevant posts to the appropriate category?? Still don't get why some people deem that irrelevant :-(

Comment: @Jay, it's not that your edit was irrelevant, it's that A) modifying tags can be done with the "edit tags" link that appears to the right of the tags (no need to suggest edits for tags) and B) if there are other issues in a post that need to be fixed and you only fix one of them, then the edit is "too minor". As both Lucifer and Michael P suggests, try fixing *all* of the problems with the post so your edits are "substantive". Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the background.. look's like I'm still [a couple points short](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) of *Editing Tags* (<500)