# Do not allow edits on different posts within 5 minutes

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

We have discussed the problems with the "suggested edits" review queue for a while here.

Some people make extremely minor edits in quick succession.
Often it is people who make the same style of edit to a lot of posts - add or remove one specific tag to a question, only removing "Thank you" from posts, or only removing a specific keyword from the title.
Unfortunately, these extremely minor edits are often approved. The people who make these edit suggestions are then rewarded with +2 rep, and the serial approvers are closer to a badge. And since the edits were approved, the "edit ban" does not kick in.

I suggest that we do not allow people to suggest edits to different posts within 5 minutes.
This should discourage "serial minor edits", while encouraging people to take some time making proper edits.

Comment: My worry would be the "power goes to head" scenario when the user hits 2k. They not only get the ability to edit freely but are no longer rate-limited either.

Comment: @Ben Is this an acutal problem? Do users abuse this behaviour in the way you describe?

Comment: see: [An alert to serial minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits). Also note user can be [banned from suggesting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/165773 "as explained here") if **responsible** reviewers reject a couple of their invalid suggestions

Comment: @gnat Regarding the second part, the key word is indeed "responsible". My impression is that there are not enough rejections of extremely minor edits.

Comment: I think the the way to deal with brainless reviewers is to **[make reviews flaggable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150001/165773 "as suggested here")**

Comment: @gnat I like that one! But the comment thread points out some of the practical problems. Also, as pointed out elsewhere on that page: who should review the reviewers?

Answer (score 4):

> add or remove one specific tag to a question, only removing "Thank you" from posts, or only removing a specific keyword from the title.

I don't think that what you mention are minor edits that should be discouraged. One could argue if they are worth reputation and badges. But what are +2 reputation and a bronze badge? Not much.

Comment: I don't mind a +2 for a single, very minor edit. The problem I want to address is people doing the same extremely minor edit suggestion many times, gaining "+2 times many". While helping the serial approvers to get their Reviewer and Steward badges.

Comment: Getting the silver and gold badges is already limited by the maximum of 20 such review task per day.

Comment: While I think the "20 reviews/day" limit is good, my impression is that it has not discouraged the "serial approvers" enough yet. I still see too many sugggested edits being rubber-stamped. YMMV.

Comment: The 20 reviews/day limit has also made us "serial rejecters" review fewer posts per day. Not sure if that is an overall improvement.