# Suggestion to add way to flag serial trivial editing by a user

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

It seems that some users tend to go on a reviewing spree and you see post after post by the same reviewer correcting the same thing in different answers.

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4572417) one decided to add "highlighting" to several posts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4572397) one decided that instances of "openSSL" must be changed to "OpenSSL" in several posts and caused quite a bit of approve-reject back and forth.

If it's not an option to [limit reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154906/a-suggestion-for-suggested-edit-improvement), better guidelines for reviewing are needed, and, a way to flag an editor for "serial-trivial-editing".