# How to handle high specific minor edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A user seems to have zeroed in on a single spelling error shown [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2609182).

Since most of the edits are not rejected, my questions is, Am I wrong to see it as minor edits?

If not, is there anything I could do besides rejecting?

Comment: Nothing needs to be done besides reviewing appropriately. If it's the only issue in the entire post, accept. If there are multiple other issues, reject as too minor. That would be my approach. You could opt to leave a comment to the editor, but make it constructive if you do.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits

Comment: (Really, the problem is not the person suggesting the edits. It's the people reviewing them giving him 54 rep for trivial edits, which teaches him to keep doing it).

Comment: Looking at said editor's suggested edits, I see "ho ho ho ho...". Man, people are sloppy with their question title.

Comment: I've got an idea: All the 2k ers go fix all the ho's. Problem solved.

Comment: Title is important, so fixing it is NOT minor. When the post itself contains other problems than only fixing the title looks like pure rep mining so rejecting is justified but if the post is OK, even one letter fix in title is valid in my opinion and usually I would approve it.

Comment: I have once suggested to [demand some time between edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154893/168333) to discourage serial editing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd So, would you have approved my edit to *this* question? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yup! Worth to mention I was going to reject Vigbyor's edit as too minor or invalid then realized the post needs to be improved and was too lazy to do that myself so decided to let others do it. :)

Comment: I think "ho" is an inappropriate word on SO, so editing them out of title is a good thing

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree with this point of view, but I'm not sure if this kind of serial edit should be supported.

Comment: There no such thing "serial edit", at least not in a bad way. When an action is helpful, there's nothing wrong in repeating it over and over. Same with flags... there's no "serial flagging" right?

Comment: @AndrewBarber one of the differences would be no one has to review it (serial), the second you do not earn `needed` reputaion, third you are doing it where you are seeing an actual problem.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The conclusion is the title is excluded from minor edits and if ther are no furthor problems it should be approved?

Comment: I'm not in the position to make any rules, but yes this concludes my own personal opinion.

Comment: @bummi You're not wrong to see these as too minor. Not *all* of them are, but the vast majority fall in to that category. I spent almost my entire edit review allocation today rejecting edits from that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think these edits are fine when you got 2k rep and no one needs to review them. However, they are too minor when reviewed and should be flagged as such. The problem is however not the user, but the reviewers telling the user that this is ok.