# Allow me to make the same tag edit on more than three questions if the first edits have been approved

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, edits

I'm currently fixing mistagged questions pertaining to the [Haskell stack tool](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/). This means that I'm replacing a lot of `stack` tags with `haskell-stack` tags. What slows me down is that I can edit only three questions before I'm blocked from editing any further questions until my first edits have been reviewed.

It would be nice if I could be allowed to just edit all of them in one go, once my first edits have been approved.

Comment: I notice that this retagging effort appears to never have been brought up on Stack Overflow Meta. I really suggest you post it there, for two reasons: The community could disagree with your efforts and explain why it's a bad idea, _or_ the community can _help_ retag these. While I don't know how other communities feel about the issue, on Stack Overflow at least, we'd rather you bring it up for discussion with the community, _especially_ as a <2k rep user. I suggest using the `[retag-request]` tag.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks, I wasn't aware of Stack Overflow Meta! [I have brought up the issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340785/retag-questions-with-haskell-and-stack-to-haskell-stack-if-they-pertain-to).

Answer (score 12):

The [rate limit was created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits) to combat the exact situation you describe. Users flooding the review queue with tag edits like this is annoying and sometimes users do it without thinking it through or discussing whether it's the correct thing to do with the community first.

The rate limit is very intentional, and exempting tag-only edits like this would completely defeat the purpose of its creation, which is to prevent tag-only edits like this.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! It seems to me that the rate limit is in place to prevent flooding with _low quality_ edits that will typically be rejected. Once a bunch of edits is approved though, I think the rate limit should be lifted.

Comment: @sjakobi Once you reach 2,000 reputation and don't have to *suggest* edits anymore, then there is no rate limit. But while you're eating up other users' time with them, it will always exist.

Comment: Well, I can clearly understand the motivation, but hope that this policy is eventually reconsidered. Right now, it's kind of frustrating to me.

Comment: @sjakobi That's... kind of the intention. We wouldn't be effectively stopping you and getting you to discuss it with others who could even *help* with the effort if we didn't make it frustrating to do on your own.