# Editing tag description gives "no usage guidance"

Tags: support, tags, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

On Network Engineering, I've decided to update tags related to the questions asked, since there are many, that doesn't have any short or longer description.

I edited 2 or 3 tags clicking the 'Tags' menu at top and then:

[image]

[image]

Either clicking the "*help us edit this wiki*" or, when hovering over a tag, clicking the 'edit' mark.

The first ones gave no problems. But, if we use the tag ***design*** as seen on the picture (Tags, page 2), if I edit that and many others I get the following:

[image]

What is the cause of this error?

There are a lot of tags, where if I try to edit them, this message is displayed. Could it be because it hasn't been used enough or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing this post, you have [6 pending edits](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/36472/cown?tab=activity):

[image]

[The maximum is 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232) (you were able to bypass this because you submitted an excerpt and a wiki simultaneously), so you'll have to wait with editing until two of the pending edits are approved.

Also, please don't blindly copy-paste text into tag wikis. E.g. [this text](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32851) seems to be copied from [here](https://opensource.com/resources/linux). One of the rejection reasons is

> **copied content**
>
> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, i missed the point of the tags counting 2 edits.

Comment: I've noticed the last edit. If i don't manage to reedit the tags to include my own explanation, i will ask one of the moderators to reject my edits. Thanks again and sorry i've violated your rules. :-)