# Privilege level for editing tags not shown

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, privileges

On Ethereum, I have a reputation of 161 and I thought that I would add some information to the [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) tag. The header of the [USB tagged questions page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) even asks if I want to help create it:

> [image: USB tagged questions header]

However, when I click on [`help us create it`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2123), I do not see an edit tag button, and the text boxes are read-only:

> [image: USB tag info]

The description therein seems to suggest that as I have under 4000 rep, I should be able to edit and then have my edit placed in a queue. Regardless, I cannot edit the tag info.

So, I went to the [Privileges page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and looked for how much rep is required to edit tags:

> [image: List of privileges]

At 150 I can create a tag. It is unclear whether I can edit an existing tag, with or without a description already.

1. If at 150 I can edit, then:

   - Shouldn't the Privileges page say "create and edit tags", or is that just meant to be inferred by the user?.
   - If I am meant to be able to edit, then why can't I?
2. If at 150 I can not yet edit, then at what reputation can I edit tags, and why isn't it listed in the Privileges page?

Something seems wrong here, and there seems to be a confusion in the guidance; "users with under 4000 reputation points" and the ability to create tags (but can you edit them?) at 150 reputation points. Given that I am not a new user to SE, I am surprised that I don't know what is happening. If I don't, then surely a new SE user will be even more confused.

It would be nice to see the definitive point at which I can suggest an edit to a tag in the privileges page.

If it comes at rep = 1 or 101, like suggesting a question edit, then why am I unable to edit the USB tag description?

Comment: The tag wiki page still doesn't display reasoning why the edit button is gone, because it never got those updates we applied to posts to explain the reasons. Does it appear now? It might have just been because you already had too many pending suggested edits (max 5 on a graduated site). There is no reputation requirement for suggesting edits to tag wikis, only for making those edits without peer review.

Comment: @animuson - Ah yes, I did have four (or five) pending edits, now that you mention it, which have now been accepted. And yes I can see the edit boxes now. It would have been nice to have been given a notice on that page along the lines of "you can't edit because you have too many pending edit suggestions". Should I change the meaning of this question to reflect that, or raise a new question?

Comment: Related / duplicate: [Editing tag description gives “no usage guidance”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306357/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel - yes, it looks to be the same issue... *although* the issue of the Privileges page not mentioning at reputation of 1 that you can edit tag-wikis, still stands. Come to think of it, it *also* doesn't mention that you can edit posts. Is that something that should be addressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was apparently due to the fact that I had five pending suggested edits to questions, that meant I was unable to effect my edits. Once my suggested edits had been accepted then I was then able to edit the tag wiki.

It would have been nice to have been given a notice on that page along the lines of:

> You are unable to edit this tag because you have too many pending edit suggestions. Please wait until your pending edits have been processed, ...

I have raised a new question here, [No notice of "too many pending edits" on tag edit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311805/no-notice-of-too-many-pending-edits-on-tag-edit-page)

However, the issue of the Privileges page *not* mentioning at reputation of 1 that you can edit tag-wikis, still stands. Come to think of it, it *also* doesn't mention that you can edit posts. Is that something that should be addressed?

Comment: I think it's addressed enough by the mere presence of a link to edit.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - you are quite right, of course. The main issue is the missing "too many edits" notice. If that notice was in place then I wouldn't have gone looking to see if I had the privilege to edit. I shall mark my answer as the accepted answer, when I am able (which will be tomorrow)