# No notice of "too many pending edits" on tag edit page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Referring back to this issue, [Privilege level for editing tags not shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311799/privilege-level-for-editing-tags-not-shown)

Apparently, I was unable to edit the tag wiki due to the fact that I had five pending suggested edits to questions, that meant I was unable to effect my edits. Once my suggested edits had been accepted then I was then able to edit the tag wiki.

It would have been nice to have been given a notice on the tag's [`help us to create it`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2123)  page along the lines of:

> You are unable to edit this tag because you have too many pending edit suggestions. Please wait until your pending edits have been processed, ...