Cannot create new tag wiki
I was creating tag wikis for Physical Fitness SE today and suddenly it stopped working. When I click the "help us create it" link I get redirected to the tag info page. It's happening for plates, for example, and any other tags I've tried after that. It doesn't seem to affect me on Graphic Design SE, for example (but my rep is much higher there).
Is it a bug related to New tag wikis cannot be created or I keep getting errors while trying to add a tag description on MoviesSE?

Just a thought, but maybe this should have been added to your other question from yesterday rather than posted separately...? Also, maybe not. Just saying.

@W.O. I didn't because it's a different bug, possibly affecting only Fitness.SE. But that's why I linked my other question here (I can just add it all there and delete this one if it's better)

I think there is a limit how many pending edits a user can have in same time, and you just reached that limit. The bug is not having any error message showing this. What you get when browsing directly to the edit page? Also please open the browser's developer console (F12 in Chrome) and go to Network tab, and see the server response to the request.

@W.O. this one here isn't really a bug, see duplicate.

Ohh. Got it. @ShadowWizard

@ShadowWizard console shows cookie-consent.en.js, otSDKStub.js and google tag manager scripts are blocked when I click on the edit page link, but I get the tag info page instead. No errors about pending edits.

@ShadowWizard if it's not showing an error message, then this shouldn't be closed as duplicate since it's an unresolved bug.

Well, that's a delicate meta thing. Since this is not technically a bug (as that is how the system was built from the beginning), but still something that better be changed, the correct way is starting a new feature request asking to change it. Please submit a new question as feature request, linking to the posts showing this behavior, and ask to change it so that when you have too many pending edits, you will not be able to suggest new tag wiki edits. (Which is consistent with all the rest)

@ShadowWizard sure. I just found a request for exactly this, 6 years old https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311805/no-notice-of-too-many-pending-edits-on-tag-edit-page

now I just wish someone would log in on fitness.SE and accept my edits...

@ShadowWizard check this feature request https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311805/no-notice-of-too-many-pending-edits-on-tag-edit-page
