# Can't suggest an edit on a beta site in the iOS app when I have 5 or more suggested edits pending

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ios-app, beta-sites

It looks like the Stack Exchange iOS app has some built-in protection where you cannot suggest edits on a site where you already have 5 or more pending suggested edits. That makes sense, but for beta sites the limit is [20, not 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232). So I'm not able to suggest edits on Freelancing right now; the edit button is missing:

[image]

In case development on the mobile apps ever gets resumed again, this would be 'low hanging fruit'.