# You can propose six Tag Wiki edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

According to [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) you can propose five edits at one time:

> ### When can I not suggest an edit?
>
> You have 5 suggested edits pending (20 on beta sites). Wait for one of them to be reviewed.

I found a way to propose six edits:

1. Edit 4 tag wikis/excerpts
2. Go to edit a tag
3. Edit both the tag wiki and the excerpt

You have six suggested edits:

[image]

Whilst when having five suggested edits you can't suggest anymore. Is this supposed to happen or not?

Comment: A [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits#comment913507_281202) from Shog on the answer announcing the rate limit suggests this is intentional.