# Where is the edit tag button?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt

I'd like to change a tag description, but there's not button or link to edit the tag.

A page without a description says "The [tag] has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?". But I can't find out why.

If there is any reason that I can't edit this tag, please add some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're on a site where you have that privilege? I have definitely looked for privileges on sites where I didn't actually have them.

Comment: Are you logged in on SO?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in. And I've proposed edits before. I can even see there's a pending edit on another tag (symfony).

Comment: And if I'm not allowed to edit tags, there shouldn't be an question if I can help to create one.

Comment: The only time I've ever seen that button not present is if I'm logged out.

Comment: Please add your browser etc. to narrow down the problem.

Comment: You have 5 pending edits. You have to wait until those are reviewed

Comment: If I'm not logged in, there is no "can you help us create it?" either. I'm definitely logged in, I have edited tags in the past. The button has disappeared recently.

Comment: better duplicate even: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @rene I liked your first dupe better. This tells what happened, not why the button isn't there (which is terrible UX IMHO, it's better to gray it out or something.)

Comment: @Luuklag Hmm, okay. "better" then ;)

Comment: What a shame that this UX fail hasn't been fixed. Very easy to fix.

Comment: @StephanVierkant nothing is easy to fix... poking at code will inevitably introduce more bugs which have to be found, and the whole process eats up precious developer time.

Comment: I know it can introduce more bugs. But copy `if(canEditTags() { showEditButton(); }` to `if (canEditTags()) { echo "can you help us create it"; }` shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405981/stephan-vierkant?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) says you have five pending suggested edits ([Wayback Machine link for posterity](https://web.archive.org/web/20210806201543/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405981/stephan-vierkant?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)). On non-beta sites, [five is the maximum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232). You'll have to wait until one of those gets accepted or rejected; then, the edit button will appear again.

Comment: Glorfindel saves the day :)