# Pending Edits, and Limit on Number of Edits

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

I am trying to Edit the questions posted on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). But, I am receiving this:

> You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted
> until prior edits have been approved.

My queries are:

**a.** What is the daily/weekly limit on number of edits?
**b.** How to speed up the process of approving prior edits?

I have explored all existing questions, but haven't obtained a standard answer.

Comment: You can have a look at the section about suggested edits here: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899). It says that there are at most 5 pending edits (with some exceptions) and links to this post: [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416#281202).

Comment: Regarding your other questions: b) No limit on amount of edits, the limit is only on amount of pending edits that were not rejected or approved yet. c) If you see suggested edits taking very long to get approved, not only yours, post on the per-site meta about it, asking more users to take part.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to speed up approvals, it is up to users with sufficient privileges to review the suggested edit queue. Only a few people want to do this.