# Edit option disable suddenly

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

In my Stack Overflow Account, suddenly I am not able to edit any Question asked and I am also not able to edit any answer also. Anyone know the reason behind this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [This is the Stack Overflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1553563/androidlearner) recognizable by the same gravatar... Correct me if I'm wrong @AndroidLearner :)

Comment: Don't you get any message when you hover over the "edit" link?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At least 6 out of 10 of [your last suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553563/androidlearner?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) have been rejected. Which means that your suggested edits are not particularly good. At some point the system will put your edit privileges on hold and you will no longer be able to suggest edits. This is most likely what happened to you. A ban AFAIK usually [lasts for 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192).

I would suggest that you go through your suggested edits and see why they were rejected. Use that information to find out how you can improve your edits once you are allowed to make them again.

Going through some of the first:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047031
  It is perfectly fine to say "I'm". The change to "I am" is unnecessary. I don't know why you changed "min" to "Minimum". If it's not wrong to begin with ("min" might be something SDK specific there) it's not really necessary. Too minor as a result
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047028
  Correction of "basically" is fine. Correction of "happens" is wrong ("happends" is incorrect). And don't edit in "Thanks in advance". Leave that out of posts.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047000
  Correction of "Android" is okay. Editing in "Any thoughts?" is completely unnecessary. You didn't remove "Thanks" and the rest of the post could do with a touch-up as well.

That should at least give you some idea. Go through the rest of them and see what you could have done better. Even look at your question here and its original revision. Then have a look at what Yannis did to that to whip it into shape. See the difference?

Once you have the edit privilege again, don't edit a whole bunch of posts at the same time. Edit one very carefully. See if it gets accepted. If so, do another one. If not, learn from it and once you understand why not, go on to the next one.

Comment: How can i know the exact reason behind this and is there any way that i can get that privilege back?

Comment: If you go to each suggested edit, you can see who rejected your edits and what their particular motivation was. Whether it was too minor. If it was wrong. Changed the post too much, etc.

Comment: And one note: [Please don't edit in "Thanks in advance"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047028). If anything, you should remove it from posts when you edit them.

Comment: _lasts for 7 days_ hmm per my recollection about a year and half ago, [6 rejections resulted in two weeks ban](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XJWwR.png)

Comment: @gnat Hmm, I got it from here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192 as linked from the ["How do suggested edits work"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) FAQ page. If you have more up-to-date info, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: @Bart well ["currently 7" answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/165773) is quite old, Feb 2011, but my own data isn't much better either - July '11. Mine is formally _more up-to-date_ but certainly not good enough for a definitive statement on how things are _now_

Comment: @gnat I could make it AFAGK...as far as Gnat knows... ;)

Comment: @Bart thanks to point me in the right direction about how editing of the question should be done.Is there any way that i can get back this privilege?

Comment: If the ban is for 7 days you can get it back by waiting for 7 days.

Comment: Is it possible to know the duration of ban?

Comment: Which part of "7 days" is unclear exactly?

Comment: @Bart you said "if the ban is for 7 days".So I just want to make sure that I am being punished for the 7 days or more.

Comment: User gnat seems to think it might be longer. All evidence I have says 7 days. So that's it for now. If I'm able to confirm otherwise I'll update the answer. But long story short, all you can do is sit and wait until you get it back. Whenever that may be.

Comment: @Bart yes you are right..Thanks for your help :)

Comment: :) @Bart it is probably more interesting that OP acts surprised ("suddenly I am not able...") while per my recollection, back then there was a message clearly explaining **why** I am suspended and **for how long**. If _that_ message is gone now, it would be a great pity... Maybe I'll test that with one of my low-rep accounts (eg account I used some time ago to test for [particular bug with flagging summary links](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPqMh.jpg))

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern among your suggested edits are that you add sentences like "[Thanks in advance ...](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047028)", "[Any thoughts?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047000)" and so on. Such [expressions are actually frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) at Stack Overflow and they should ideally be removed by an edit, not added.

Other times you are simply not solving the problems with the post. A spell correction should optimally fix all or most of all errors, not just a single word. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047028) where you swapped a incorrect spelling into another just as incorrect one, and you also left the many misspellings of "Android", "due the new" and some other stylistic problems.

You also seems to like uppercasing random words. Why do you feel that "[app](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1046517)" and "[minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047031)" should be spelled with a leading uppercase letter? They are perfectly normal words, not names.