# I can't edit posts. Help!

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a penalty for one’s edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected)

I improved posts. I added tags. After two edits "edit" button has been disabled. Why  I can't edit ?

Comment: Hover over the edit button and see what the tooltip says...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see 5 rejected suggestions of yours recently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1414980), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1414336), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1414332), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1413159), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1408336)), so it would appear that enough of your posts have been rejected to ban you from suggesting new edits (temporarily, it's a 7 day ban).  I suggest you spend some time looking through your [suggestion history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1952862/ty221?tab=activity) to see what edits are rejected and why, and which ones are approved, so that you can stop suggesting edits that don't conform to the sites's guidelines.

Looking at your recent edits, they are almost entirely just tag edits; you are not fixing any of the the other problems with posts, and this is resulting in them being rejected as "too minor".  You should strive to fix *all* problems with a post (at least try to fix everything you feel that you can fix) rather than looking for just one problem and not even attempting to review large sections of a post.

Comment: to be specific, you tend to add tags and make very tiny edits (change java to javascript) but leave a lot of other problems unchanged. This makes extra work for the reviewers. If you're going to edit a post, fix everything that needs fixing. Some of the edits that were approved, I would have rejected as too minor. I know it might seem that when you first start, just do little fixes, but because others need to review it's important to do the whole job the first time.

Comment: How is it bad to fix something correctly? If all he sees is a tag fix, and the tag fix is CORRECT that seems pretty worthwhile to prevent something from coming up under the wrong tags.  If it was just tiny grammar edits with many others remaining I'd agree with the minor thing.