# What caused review to cease for this item?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

Apparently [this review item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/11545) was created by a possible duplicate flag, as there is only one close vote on the corresponding question, and a single review with a vote to close.

Sounds good so far, except that the item is no longer reviewable. Why is that? There were never any Leave Open votes, and there's only one vote to close. It seems to me it should still be going to gather either four more close votes or three Leave Open votes.

Is this some sort of bug with flags being handled by the review queue that causes review to complete prematurely?

Comment: Related (but not necessarily a duplicate): [What can cause “This item is no longer reviewable”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156120/what-can-cause-this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable)

Comment: my guess for this case is, item got 3x (or whatever amount needed to pull it off the queue) "Leave Open" actions

Comment: @gnat: The first and only review for the item was a Close action.

Comment: It already had 4 close votes when I reviewed it.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: Could be possible that it had 4 flags on it? There definitely weren't any other votes to close on it.

Comment: Strange, it did show 4 flags. But there are more strange things today with reviewing. I have some "hanging" reviews at SO that refuse to load.

Comment: @animuson you're right, "Leave Open" should have been displayed there. Hm. At <70 views, and less than a day since close vote (indicated by [standard "possible duplicate" comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165491/i-cant-edit-posts-help#comment483425_165491)), votes couldn't expire either. I wouldn't expect "skip" actions to do magic like that, either. Hmmmmm "curiouser and curiouser..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fixed now. Here's what happened:

The post was enqueued in the Close Votes queue via a single close *flag*. When Toon cast his close vote, the close flag was automatically dismissed as "helpful". Since the queue only includes posts with close flags/votes cast more than 15 minutes ago, it was no longer considered reviewable since Toon's vote replaced the flag, and was cast within the past 15 minutes.

**Edit**: I re-enabled the [review item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/11545) in question.