# Account restricted to edit posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I cannot edit any posts on SO except mine. Why has this happened? It displays a message that This account is not allowed to suggest edits. When I willbe able to suggest edits again? and How?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly because you kept making edits that were rejected.

Have a look through your suggested edits (browse the activity tab in your profile and click suggestions) and see why they were rejected, then change how you edit.

I checked a few and you're using backticks too much - keep it for actual code.
Sometimes you're making unnecessary small or cosmetic changes - try to focus on improving the spelling, grammar, phrasing or code layout, and make sure you've made a real difference rather than a little one.

Read [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled). You'll probably be able to edit again in 7 days.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I am wrong..That is what I needed..

Comment: @BhushanFirake I've added more advice now that I've read a larger number of your edit suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

If you have too many rejected suggested edits in too short a period of time the system cuts you off. Assuming nothing untoward happens, you should be able to suggest edits again in 7 days.

Comment: Oh my..! Thank you for the quick answer....!!