# What should I do with suggested edits adding salutations to a post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was [under the impression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that editing out 'thanks' from the end of a post was what we wanted.

I just reviewed a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1758866) where the 'thanks' seemed to be on the wrong side until I realised they were adding it back in. [Further digging](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15539211/revisions) revealed it had been previously removed.

I had also just reviewed [another suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1758871) from the same user which added 'Please help me in this' from out of nowhere as far as I can tell.

Should I just be rejected edits like this or should I flag if they are coming from the same user?

Comment: Reject them if it is the only thing. Edit the post to remove them, if other edits are significant enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *is* possible that the user started editing from a different revision that then carried over into the suggested edit as "adding things" (which were previously removed). So evaluate the post without those and if the other edits are worthy then just improve it to remove those things again. Flagging is not necessary in either case, as enough rejections will cause an automatic ban.

In your first example, [this appears to be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15539211/revisions) (although that's still a reject-worthy edit). Your second example appears to be randomly adding it in, though.

Answer (score 5):

Rejecting is enough IMHO. If some of his/hes suggestion get rejected he/she will get [edit suggestion ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/187824).