# Reject suggested edit cooldown

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I am a frequent reviewer, mostly in suggested edits, and something I notice a lot is people submitting the same kinds of stupid and incorrect suggested edits over and over, most of the time being rejected, but occasionally being accepted by lazy-reviewers. There is generally loads of unnecessary suggested edits in the queue (although not as many as there are in the close votes-queue), and people never quite seem to learn.

A way to prevent more of these edits could be to put users submitting three rejected edits on a cooldown for a day or more, presenting it with a page/guide for how to correctly edit posts.

I'm adding this as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), let me know if you think this is a good idea or not, or what could improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/