# Is it legitimate to mass retag questions without edit privileges?

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I've recently started with a large retag on the new [Quantum Computing site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com). I first discussed with a user who can review and we thought that we knew what needed to be done.

However, it appears that 1 or 2 tags per edit were not to the other users' liking after all and hence I've had enough rejects to be temporarily banned from making more (how long? perhaps this should be mentioned on that page).

I've been one of the most active edit queue fillers of the site, but I needed a break anyway, so I don't mind the ban.

So, what I'm thinking that would be best is

### Do not massively retag or edit without edit privileges

Or at least be very careful when doing so.

Is this good advice? Or are there other tricks?

Comment: Actually, making a "deal" with someone to approve all your edits is on the verge of abusing the system, same as using sock puppet account, and is reason for suspension. So consider yourself lucky you're not suspended there. (Probably because there are no moderators, and/or your past positive behavior)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't make a 'deal', I talked about what I was about to do and I heard approval from an user that could approve it. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I mean, the fact that that user rejected most of my edits shows there wasn't a 'deal' of any kind!

Comment: That wasn't clear at all from the way you posted this. Still, same user reviewing all edits of other user is potential for abuse, so better avoid it in the first place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but there were only 2 users capable of review... (beta)

Comment: Yet again, please clarify this in your question. (For the record, I upvoted since it's a legit discussion,  but suspect most downvotes are due to this being "fishy")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### Do not massively retag or edit without edit privileges

Yes, this is definitely good advice. This way, it's done the quickest and there will be no (maybe unfounded) accusations of rep-farming. But *even* for those with edit privileges, here are some tips & tricks:

- make sure you have support from the community in the form of a well-received [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) on the site's own meta
- provide a link to said meta post in your edit summary
- fix other issues (typos, grammar, formatting) in the post
- do not edit too much posts at once as this will bump a lot of old questions to the front page (less of a problem on a private beta, but it can still be annoying)
- if all questions tagged [x] need to be tagged [y], ask a ♦ moderator to merge/synonymize them (again, this is less likely to work on a private beta)

If you are still set on retagging via suggested edits,

- do **not** ask somebody to mass approve your edits. This can be seen as voting fraud!

---

> (how long? perhaps this should be mentioned on that page)

[7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/295232).

Comment: This answer is bit.. messy. Think the "leave the edits to someone with edit privileges" is the desired answer, since the whole point in this specific question is doing this without edit privilege, so all the rest is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I'll promote that to the main point (I originally wrote the answer on mobile).

Comment: Maybe TL;DR as first paragraph, then the rest, more general, tips?

Comment: How do you like my new version?

Comment: The +10 in your pocket tells it all. ;-)

Comment: What if you suggest the edits as an anonymous user, so as to avoid earning rep for the edits? Also, what if you've already gained 1,000 rep from approved edits, so future approvals don't add to your rep?

Comment: I consider the rep-farming to be only a minor point in my answer. It's still much quicker if done by privileged users.